# How do I use if condition in where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I use if condition in where condition

I want to use settle_date when the trans_date is null;

```
select * from test
where date(trans_date) = '2022-05-01'
```

How do I have date(settle_date) = '' when trans_date is null?

Comment: you can find tutorials for this here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE DATE(COALESCE(trans_date, settle_date)) = '2022-05-01';
```

Note that if the `trans_date` and `settle_date` columns are already dates, you don't need to cast to date:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE COALESCE(trans_date, settle_date) = '2022-05-01';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values by another value. So in your case you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE DATE(COALESCE(trans_date, settle_date)) = '2022-05-01';
```

If these columns are datetime, i.e. have a time component, then don't cast to date but instead use:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE COALESCE(trans_date, settle_date) >= '2022-05-01' AND
      COALESCE(trans_date, settle_date) <  '2022-05-02';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IFNULL:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date(ISNULL(trans_date,settle_date))='2022-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although "COALESCE" is the best answer, you also do it like this:

```
SELECT oneField,
    CASE
        WHEN trans_date IS NULL THEN settle_date 
        ELSE trans_date 
    END AS myDate,
    otherField
FROM someTable
```